# change php search url to short url using php and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, seo

my search url is long , how to change this to short url firndly url using php & mod_rewrite ?

MY URL :

```
mydomain.com/gosearch.php?page=1&random=742&title=test&loc1=ANY&loc2=ANY&loc3=ANY&t=ALL&st=3&app=5&image=ALL
```

I like To : hidden all after page number ( in e.x is 1 )

```
     mydomain.com/search/1/
```

OR

```
     mydomain.com/search/1/742/test/ANY/ANY/ANY/ALL/3/5/ALL
```

Thanks.

Comment: there's nothing SEO unfriendly about query strings - they are just not as readable but `search/1/` isn't any better

Comment: yes, but my mean Better appearance of url. short url is better. i dont need to optimized for search engine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)/ /gosearch.php?page=$1&amp;random=$2 [L]
```

but it can get quite ugly and would work only up to 9 parameters

better is to redirect all traffic going to search to the php script (gosearch.php) and then parse the request and/or query string in php and handle appropriately, e.g.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/search(.*)$
RewriteRule . /gosearch.php [L, QSA]
```

and then in gosearch.php

```
<?php

    $paramaters = explode( '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

    print_r( $parameters );
?>
```

and take it from there

p.s. the `QSA` will add any query string from /search/1/ so the query parameters can be accessed the usual way via `$_GET` / `$_REQUEST`